# Finding the number of permutations on $\{1,2,3,..,n\}$ under some restrictions

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ .

For a permutation  $P=(P(1),P(2),P(3)....,P(n))$ of the elements of $A$ , let $P(1)$ denote the first element of $P$ . Find the number of all such permutations $P$ so that for all $i,j \in A$

- If $i\lt j \lt P(1) $, then $j$  appears before $i$ in $P$
- If $P(1) \lt i \lt j$ then $i$ appears before $j$ in $P$

I know that this is previuosly asked question  ([Permutation such that • if i < j < P(1), then j appears before i in P; and • if P(1) < i < j,then i appears before j in P](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784898/710290)) but unfortunately I am not quite satisfied with the answers especially with the numeric value and particularly the approach. . So here's my thinking .

My Thinking :

Clearly , the elements above $P(1)$ are in ascending order and the elements below it are in descending order where I am assuming  $1\lt P(1) \lt n$

To gain an understanding of how this works.

Let $n=10$ . Then $A=\{1,2,3,..,10\}$

If $P(1)=7$  , then the relative arrangement between the elements of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $(6 ,5, 4 ,3, 2, 1)$ and that of the elements of the set $\{8,9,10\}$ is $(8,9,10)$

Now I need to find all the permutations that can be formed  by merging the above two arrangements and then adjoin $P(1)=7$  at the beginning to get a full permutation of $A$ which satisfies the conditions.

Ok , that means I have to think  what numbers from the set $\{ 8,9 ,10\}$ can be placed in the following blanks and in how many ways

_ $6 $_ $5 $_ $4$_ $3$ _ $2$ _ $1$_

where one blank can contain more than one number from the above set. Note that I am only worried about the distinct distributions that can be made in the blank places and not on the orders in which they are distributed since there is only way they can be in ascending order.

This leads me to conclude that the required no. of such distributions and hence the  required no. of such permutations is given by  the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7=3 
\quad (*) $
where each $0\le x_i \le 3, i=1(1) 7$

So my answer should be the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^7$

Am I on the right track ??

Now, thinking to generalise this, shouldn't the answer be

The requiered no. of such permutations is  the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in the expansion of

$(1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-k})^k$ where $P(1)=k$ .

Need your guidance. Please help.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: What dissatisfies you with the linked answers? If you apply the method of Brian Scott's answer to your example, you get $\binom{9}{3}=84$. By your method, you get the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^7$, which is also the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)^7$. This is the same as the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1-x)^{-7}$. By the generalized binomial theorem, this is $\binom{-7}{3}(-1)^3$, which equals $(-1)^3(-7)(-8)(-9)/3!$, in agreement with Brian Scott's answer.

Comment: To understand Brian Scott's approach, let $L$ stand for any of the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, and let $U$ stand for any of the numbers $8$, $9$, $10$. So you need a nine-letter word made using six $L$s and three $U$s. There are $\binom{9}{3}$ such words.

Comment: All right sir , no need to be sorry ..Appreciate your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$. say, $P(1) = k \,$ where $1 \le k \le n$.

Now you have set $A(1)$ with $(k-1)$ elements sorted in one order and set $A(2)$ with $(n-k)$ elements sorted in another, totaling to $(n-1)$ elements. The internal order of $A(1)$ and $A(2)$ is fixed. You can choose $(k-1)$ positions from a total of $(n-1)$ positions in $^{(n-1)}C_{(k-1)}$ ways. Once you choose positions of $A(1)$, their order is fixed and the positions of $A(2)$ is also fixed and so is their order. **So the problem just reduces to choosing $(k-1)$ or $(n-k)$ positions from total of $(n-1)$ positions.**

So, the answer is simply $^{(n-1)}C_{(k-1)} \,$ where $k = P(1), 1 \le k \le n$.

Comment: Ah ! All right . That's the small point I was missing . We just need to select $k-1$ places from the $n-1$ avalaible places which would definitely preserve the relative orders. Thanks a lot .!!